# Access a list of entries in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a huge matrix `MxN` matrix, say, `A=rand([M,N]);` and an index vector with `N` integer values between `1` and `M`, say, `RandomIndex = randi(M,[1,N]);`.

Now I would like to generate a row vector with entries

```
result = [A(RandomIndex(1),1), A(RandomIndex(2),2), ..., A(RandomIndex(N),N)]
```

What would be an efficient way to do this? It should be a very cheap operation but all my implementations are slow. I don't think there is a notation in Matlab to do this directly, is there?

The fastest option so far is

```
indexFunction = @(r,c) A(r,c);
result = cell2mat(arrayfun(indexFunction,RandomIndex,1:N,'UniformOutput',false));
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`sub2ind`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html)

```
A(sub2ind(size(A), RandomIndex, 1:N))
```

[`sub2ind`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) will convert the row and column indices given by `RandomIndex` and `1:N` to linear indices based on `size(A)` which you can then use to index `A` directly.

---

Another way to do this is to use `RandomIndex` and `1:N` to return an `NxN` matrix and then take the diagonal of this with [`diag`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html)

```
diag(A(RandomIndex, 1:N)).'
```

**Note**: `.'` is used to convert the row vector returned by [`diag`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) to a column vector.

Comment: Plus 1 for being the first **correct** answer to this problem.

Comment: It turns out, that replicating sub2ind for this special case manually is even faster, that is `A(M*(0:(N-1)) + RandomIndex)`

Answer (score 2):

```
M=10;N=50;
A=rand([M,N]);
RandomIndex = randi(M,[1,N]);
out = zeros(1,numel(RandomIndex));
for ii = 1:numel(RandomIndex)
    out(ii)=A(RandomIndex(ii),ii);
end
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the correct values. Your code produces `A(RandomIndex, 1)`.

Comment: Stupid MATLAB not doing what I expect from it... well, then it's back to the trusty `for` loop

Comment: This is also correct.  The most canonical way to do it. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) and logical indexing:

```
M = sparse(RandomIndex, 1:N, 1) == 1;
out = A(M);
```

The first line of code generates a logical matrix where there is only 1 `true` value set in each column.  This is defined by each value of `RandomIndex`.  We convert this to a `logical` matrix, then index into your matrix to obtain the final random vector.

Answer (score 0):

Use your index directly.

```
M = 100;N=100;
A = rand(M,N);
% get a random index that can be as large as your matrix
% 10 rows by 1 column
idx = randi(numel(A), 10,1);
t = A(idx);
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the correct values. Your code produces `A(RandomIndex, 1)`.

Comment: @IKavanagh it most certainly does not produce `A(RandomIndex,1)`.  First off there is no `RandomIndex` so nice try.  Second there is no reason it is limited to `A(<any number>, 1)` since it uses a random index of all entries in `A`.  Had you bothered to run the code you would see that `idx(1) = 8148` which is element `A(82,48)` .  But hey...why bother...just troll...

Comment: This doesn't produce what the OP is looking for. Its pretty clear from his question. He has `A` and he has `RandomIndex` if he was to apply `RandomIndex` to `A` as in your question like `t = A(RandomIndex);` it will produce `A(RandomIndex, 1)` just like in my comment. How is `idx(1) = 8148` and `A(82,48)` in any way related to the question?

Comment: @IKavanagh is correct. The question is asking to generate random row locations, yet the column locations are in a pre-defined order: `col = 1, 2, ..., N`.  Essentially, the OP wants to generate: `A(random_number_1, 1), A(random_number_2, 2), ..., A(random_number_N, N)`.  This code does not do what the OP asks.  Mainly it **does not guarantee** that the column access is in the way that the OP is asking for. You are generating column-major indices and that's great, but it doesn't do it in the right order.